# C# How to combine the picturebox click event to the corresponding function?

Tags: c#, picturebox

C# How to combine the picturebox click event  to the corresponding function?

```
private void pbx_process(int i) 
{ 
   PictureBox picture_box 
      = this.Controls.Find("pbx_image" + i, true).FirstOrDefault() 
        as PictureBox; 
   if (picture_box.Image != null) pbx_image.Image = picture_box.Image; 
   else pbx_image.Image = null; 
} 

private void pbx_image1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    pbx_process(1); 
}

private void pbx_image2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    pbx_process(2); 
}

private void pbx_image3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    pbx_process(3); 
}
```

i want to make these simple. Please help....

Comment: Can you add the definition of the function `pbx_process` as well, please? From this code, it looks as though they carry out distinctly different actions based on the parameter being passed and therefore not much can be done to simplify them from what they currently do.

Comment: Well you could check the name of the sender, and extract the number off the end to call as a parameter.. but not necessarily simpler.

Comment: If your pixture box's have a 'parameter' to send to a function maybe set the parameter in the tag then you do `((PictureBox)sender).Tag` (you only need to cast it to an int). Other than that its not very clear what you want and what you tried

Comment: private void pbx_process(int i)
        {
            PictureBox picture_box = this.Controls.Find("pbx_image" + i, true).FirstOrDefault() as PictureBox;
            if (picture_box.Image != null) pbx_image.Image = picture_box.Image;
            else pbx_image.Image = null;
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a function like this

```
AddEvent()
{
pbx_image1.click+=pbx_image_Click;
pbx_image2.click+=pbx_image_Click;
pbx_image3.click+=pbx_image_Click;
}
```

then

```
private void pbx_image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 

    pbx_process(sender as PictureBox); or you can do the process right here
}
```

and then

```
private void pbx_process(PictureBox pictureBox) 
{ 

   if (pictureBox.Image != null) pbx_image.Image = pictureBox.Image; 
   else pbx_image.Image = null; 
}
```

remember to call AddEvent function once your form is loaded to add events to picture boxes.